# Getting the absolute location of a QT widget nested in multiple layouts

Tags: qt

I'd like to get the absolute location of a QT widget that is a (horizontal) layout which is itself located in a central widget that has a layout.

I've tried the `QWidget::mapToGlobal` and `QWidget::mapTo` but I keep getting `(0,0)`.

**Edit**
Here's my current implementation

```
QPoint p( 0 , 0 );  // Recall that widget 'lineEdit' is in a layout, which is itself in a layout
QPoint point = ui.lineEdit->mapToGlobal( p );
```

Comment: Have you checked the x and y of the parameters being passed to mapToGlobal? Are you sure that they're not (0,0)?

Comment: They are (0,0). I don't know what values to supply to the function.

Comment: Please show how do you pass parameters to mapToGlobal() function. Where these x and y come from?

Comment: By 'absolute location', do you mean screen coordinates? Also, as @vahancho states, please provide code.

Comment: @Merlin069 I don't mean screen coordinates. I mean the position of the widget relative to the top left corner of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Absolute location" is meaningless.

[QWidget::mapToGlobal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal), as the docs state:-

> "Translates the widget coordinate pos to global screen coordinates",

This is not want you want, as you mention in the comments that you're looking for "*the position of the widget relative to the top left corner of the window*"

You can use the function [QWidget::mapTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo), but note the following in the documentation:-

> *The parent must not be 0 and **must be a parent of the calling widget***.

From the code you've added to the example, it looks like you've used Qt Designer to create and setup the widgets. As you're calling mapToGlobal, there are only two reasons for the mapToGlobal to return (0, 0):-

1) The widget's top left corner is actually at the top left of the screen

2) I suspect you're calling the map functions before the window and its widgets have been displayed on the screen.

Without seeing all your code, I would say that no. 2 is the most likely issue here, so you're calling the mapping functions in something like the constructor of the MainWindow.

Comment: You are right. I did create my UI in QtDesigner and I am calling `mapTo` in the constructor main Window before `show()` is called.

Comment: Great, if that's solved it for you, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: It certainly pointed me in the right direction. `QWidget::mapToGlobal()` appears to return screen coordinates. As such I'm using `QWidget::mapToParent()`.